# Pythonic way to parse list of dictionaries for a specific attribute?

Tags: python, django

I want to cross reference a dictionary and django queryset to determine which elements have unique `dictionary['name']` and `djangoModel.name` values, respectively.  The way I'm doing this now is to:

- Create a list of the dictionary['name'] values
- Create a list of djangoModel.name values
- Generate the list of unique values by checking for inclusion in those lists

This looks as follows:

```
alldbTests = dbp.test_set.exclude(end_date__isnull=False)   #django queryset

vctestNames = [vctest['name'] for vctest in vcdict['tests']]   #from dictionary
dbtestNames = [dbtest.name for dbtest in alldbTests]    #from django model

# Compare tests in protocol in fortytwo's db with protocol from vc

obsoleteTests = [dbtest for dbtest in alldbTests if dbtest.name not in vctestNames]
newTests = [vctest for vctest in vcdict if vctest['name'] not in dbtestNames]
```

It feels unpythonic to have to generate the intermediate list of names (lines 2 and 3 above), just to be able to check for inclusion immediately after.  Am I missing anything?  I suppose I could put two list comprehensions in one line like this:

```
obsoleteTests = [dbtest for dbtest in alldbTests if dbtest.name not in [vctest['name'] for vctest in vcdict['tests']]]
```

But that seems harder to follow.

**Edit**:
Think of the initial state like this:

```
# vcdict is a list of django models where the following are all true
alldBTests[0].name == 'test1'
alldBTests[1].name == 'test2'
alldBTests[2].name == 'test4'

dict1 = {'name':'test1', 'status':'pass'}
dict2 = {'name':'test2', 'status':'pass'}
dict3 = {'name':'test5', 'status':'fail'}

vcdict = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
```

I can't convert to sets and take the difference unless I strip things down to just the name string, but then I lose access to the rest of the model/dictionary, right?  Sets only would work here if I had the same type of object in both cases.

Comment: Would you mind providing some sample data?  It would make the question easier to visualize. However, without looking too deeply into it, if you're just looking for unique members across 2 distinct lists of names, this seems like a perfect place to compare two `set()` containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vctestNames = dict((vctest['name'], vctest) for vctest in vcdict['tests'])
dbtestNames = dict((dbtest.name, dbtest) for dbtest in alldbTests)

obsoleteTests = [vctestNames[key]
                 for key in set(vctestNames.keys()) - set(dbtestNames.keys())]

newTests = [dbtestNames[key]
            for key in set(dbtestNames.keys()) - set(vctestNames.keys())]
```

Comment: Those are going to be sets of strings though.  I agree that I want to use sets, but I think my real question is "how do I use the features provided by sets while still working with the full dictionary (or django model) object?"

Comment: Er, it was perfect before the update!  it needs to be dbtestNames.keys() and vctestNames.keys() in the last two lines.  This is definitely what I was looking for though, thanks so much.

Comment: This confused me for a bit because I was thinking since there were no square brackets around the outside it wasn't a list comprehension, but something else.  Really, `dict((vctest['name'], vctest) for vctest in vcdict['tests'])` is the exact equivalent of: `[dict((vctest['name'], vctest) for vctest in vcdict['tests'])]` though.  Now I get that.

Answer (score 2):

You're working with basic set operations here. You could convert your objects to sets and just find the intersection (think Venn Diagrams):

```
obsoleteTests = list(set([a.name for a in alldbTests]) - set(vctestNames))
```

---

Sets are really useful when comparing two lists of objects (pseudopython):

```
set(a) - set(b)             = [c for c in a and not in b]
set(a) + set(b)             = [c for c in a or in b]
set(a).intersection(set(b)) = [c for c in a and in b]
```

Comment: But then obsoleteTests is a list of names, rather than models from a database - I need the full model.

Comment: Darn you Django. WHY YOU MAKE THINGS SO HARD?!?!?

Comment: See - that's the thing.  I have two lists of different types of objects - dictionaries and django models.  The only way to compare them is by their name attribute, which is different for each.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not sure that there *is* a way to do this, unless you want to subclass the `list` object and allow it to spit out properties of a set of objects.

Comment: But you know that you can access model instances as dicts?
e.g. instance.__dict__['name']

Comment: Right - Manji's solution provides a nice way to use sets and still keep the objects around basically by turning one attribute into a key and then making the value the original object.

Answer (score 2):

The `intersection`- and `difference`-operations of [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) should help you solve your problem more elegant.

But as you're originally dealing with dicts these examples and discussion may provide some inspirations: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/59875-finding-the-intersection-of-two-dicts